# Matrices as sets of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis

What exactly does it mean when someone says a matrix may be intrepreted as a set of vectors? As in:
"A matrix can be considered a set of vectors, organised as rows or columns"

It seems it would only be a set of vectors if the matrix was multiplied by a unit vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you can think of a $n \times m$ matrix as something like this:

$A = \begin{bmatrix} A_1 & A_2 & \cdots & A_m\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}B_1 \\B_2 \\ \vdots \\ B_m\end{bmatrix}$ where each $A_i$ is an $n$-dimensional column vector and each $B_i$ is an $m$-dimensional row vector.

For example:

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 9 & -13 \\20 & 5 & -6 \end{bmatrix}$

You can think of it as $\begin{bmatrix}A_1 \\A_2 \end{bmatrix}$ where  $ A_1=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 9 & -13\end{bmatrix}$ and $A_2 = \begin{bmatrix}20 & 5 & -6 \end{bmatrix}$ or you can think of it as $\begin{bmatrix} B_1 & B_2 & B_3 \end{bmatrix}$ where $B_1 =  \begin{bmatrix}1 \\20 \end{bmatrix}$, $B_2 =  \begin{bmatrix}9 \\5 \end{bmatrix}$ and $B_3 =  \begin{bmatrix}-13 \\-6 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Okay, so it specifically means Matrices as sets of COLUMN VECTORS not vectors. I guess I was getting tripped up on trying to find where direction was implied, as it is my impression that a vector is a number with direction.

Comment: @colin: Yes. It means that you think of a matrix as an array of row vectors or column vectors. You're thinking of a vector as they are used in physics, but in linear algebra we are interested in the algebraic viewpoint.

Comment: Why is the word "Vector" even used then? Does it only signify a m*1 or 1*n matrix, no other meaning beyond that, no geometric meaning?

Comment: @Colin: It's an unfortunate coincidence. Mathematicians tend to use words in an abstract way so often. For example, the set of all continuous functions on $[0,1]$ forms a vector space under addition and scalar multiplication. Therefore, functions in this vector space are called vectors! But they are functions, not vectors (in the physical sense). When a mathematician says "vector" all that he/she means is that it is "an element of a vector space".

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!! Very helpful hint for a student.

Comment: @Colin: You're welcome. Yeah, it's something common in mathematics. In fact, some authors prefer to use the term "linear space" instead of "vector space" to emphasize that we're dealing with objects that have a linear structure (i.e. they can be added and multiplied by a scalar satisfying some axioms). There's a branch of mathematics called functional analysis where you study function spaces. So, all you do is that you study the vector space of functions with an appropriate topology on it where your vectors are functions and you heavily employ linear algebra tools to study the space.

Comment: function spaces, hmm. So I take it that calculus, in its most common usage, is a part of this functional analysis. Also, since it helps me to write things down in my own words, can you tell me if this is a satisfactory, at least intuitive, definition of a vector space/linear space:

Comment: A vector/linear space is a space where objects (can be physics vectors, co-ordinates, functions) can be both scaled to arbitrary size and added together to form sum larger objects of arbitrary size, all while still being contained within the space. So this would essentially be Euclidean Space/Plane/etc. (as in R^n), Complex Space/Plane/etc. (as in C^n), and other spaces of infinite size where scaling and summation of objects would not result in the objects increasing or decreasing in dimensionality, thereby preserving their containment within the space.

Comment: It seems that last line is key, in that the objects and the space must always maintain the same dimensionality for the space to be considered a vector/linear space, maintaining it even through scaling and summation. Is this a good definition?